# Only one disappearing x-axis tick mark when re-labelling using scale_x_discrete() but others are fine

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, formatting, boxplot

I'm not sure what's going on here. I'm trying to create some boxplots, and when I change the x-axis tick names, one disappears.

```
dtv_inn_box <- ggplot(data = host_data,aes(x=host_data$`Innoculation route`, y=host_data$`Average days to viraemia`)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + theme_minimal()+
  xlab("Innoculation route")+
  ylab("Average days to viraemia")
```

[image: Boxplots without x-axis tick marks changed]

So you can clearly see the tick marks need to change so I tried this:

```
routes <- c("1/2 Subcutaneous, 1/2 Intradermal", "1/2 Subcutaneous, 1/2 Intravenous","1/3 Subcutaneous, 1/3 intradermal, 1/3 intravenous",
            "2/3 Subcutaneous, 1/3 Intradermal","4/5 Subcutaneous, 1/5 Intradermal","Infectious Culicoides bites",
            "Intradermal","Intramuscular","Intravenous","Subcutaneous","NA")

dtv_inn_box <- ggplot(data = host_data,aes(x=host_data$`Innoculation route`, y=host_data$`Average days to viraemia`)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + theme_minimal()+
  xlab("Innoculation route")+
  ylab("Average days to viraemia")+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=routes,
                   labels=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h", "i", "j", "k"))
```

But the result is that "k" gets ignored.

[image: Boxplots with changed tick marks]

Is it something to do with the last boxplot being "NA" values? It has me stumped!

Comment: I guess in your dataframe the final value in "route" is represented by missing value `NA`  (no quote) instead of string "NA", try un-quoting it in your `routes` vector